# jquery select children tag with names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

In the below shown html i have this main div as `cxfeeditem feeditem` and `there are many divs` with the same class names and structure.My question is for all the divs starting with the class name `cxfeeditem feeditem` ,how to get values for the children,

1.with class name cxfeeditem feeditem

2.class=feeditemtimestamp

3.cxcomments feeditemcomments

4.cxfeeditem feeditem

```
 <div class="cxfeeditem feeditem">
   <span class="feeditemtext cxfeeditemtext">
      This is my blog
   </span>
   <a class="feeditemtimestamp">Yesterday 2:13PM</a>
   <div class="cxcomments feeditemcomments"> 
     These are my comments
   </div>
   <div class="cxfeeditem1 feeditem1">
     My comments for the comment
   </div>  

</div>
```

**EDIT**: Output i want to alert the values like:

```
    This is my blog
    Yesterday 2:13PM
    These are my comments
    My comments for the comment
```

I tried the following but it returns null:

```
$("div.cxfeeditem.feeditem").each(function() {
   alert($(this).children('span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext').html());
   alert($(this).children('a.feeditemtimestamp').html());
   alert($(this).children('div.cxcomments.feeditemcomments').html());
   alert($(this).children('div.cxfeeditem.feeditem').html());
   break;
 });
```

Comment: Can you show, explicitly, what results you want to get from this jQuery?

Comment: @David Thomas:Please look at my edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I could see is:

```
​$('.cxfeeditem.feeditem').filter(
    function(){
        return !$(this)
            .parents('.cxfeeditem.feeditem')
            .length​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
    }).children().each(
        function(){
            console.log($(this).text().trim());
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aGQ9h/).

The `filter()` is used to ensure we're not accessing the elements of the same `.cxfeeditem` and `.feeditem` classes that are children of the outer-most element of those classes. This feels a little messy, but given your desired output it seemed the best way.

After that we're simply logging the white-space `trim()`-ed `text()` of each of the (direct) child elements that haven't been filtered-out.

---

**Edited** in response to question from the OP in comments, below:

> What if I want to add a children class name and I do not want to consider all tags; for example if I wanted the value of only `a.feeditemtimestamp` and `span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext`

In that case you can either use a second call to `filter()`:

```
$('.cxfeeditem.feeditem').filter(
    function() {
        return !$(this).parents('.cxfeeditem.feeditem').length;
    }).children().filter(
        function() {
            var that = $(this);
            return that.is('span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext, a.feeditemtimestamp');
        }).each(        
            function() {
                console.log($(this).text().trim());
            });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aGQ9h/3/).

Or you can use `find()` (and omit `children()`):

```
$('.cxfeeditem.feeditem').filter(
    function() {
        return !$(this).parents('.cxfeeditem.feeditem').length;
    }).find('> span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext, > a.feeditemtimestamp').each( 
        function() {
            console.log($(this).text().trim());
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aGQ9h/2/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).
  - [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: What if i want to add a children class name and i do not want to consider all tags..For ex: if i wanted the value of only a.feeditemtimestamp and span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext

Comment: They're all working for me (Chrome 19/Win XP); what browser/platform are you using, is your developer tools' JavaScript console open?

Comment: You don't have to apologise for that, but I'm afraid I can't tell you why something working for me isn't working for you. As to my question, though: what browser/platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

According to your function

```
alert($(this).children('span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext').html());
```

this is giving the text value of span inside the first div whose class is cxfeeditem feeditem

for second div the span is not present so null.

Comment: yes i know,the function is written to fetch the text in the span tag inside the din,the second div doesn't has a span div and so it is giving null alert the second time

Comment: the loop is running two time if you see properly
div.cxfeeditem.feeditem occurs two time

Comment: i have changed the second div name and its still null .Please see the edit in the html